# Error #1010 in level setup class

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having problem with a piece of code of mine, and it seems to be in this following class:

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
//levels are 11x9

public class Level extends MovieClip
{

    var level1:Array=new Array(
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
    var grid:Array = new Array(11);
    public function Level()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            grid.push(new Array(9));
        }
        for (var xr=0; xr<11; xr++)
        {
            for (var yr=0; yr<9; yr++)
            {
                var type = level1[yr * 11 + xr];
                var obj:Wall = new Wall(xr*50,yr*50,type);
                grid[xr][yr] = obj;
                if (type!=0)
                {
                    addChild(obj);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Now I've done some work, and the error is Error Code #1010: Term undefined and has no properties.
Even more specific, I did some debugging and determined the exact line to be
    grid[xr][yr]=obj;
Any help is appreciated.
    enter code here
    enter code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
grid.push(new Array(9));
```

to

```
grid[i]=new Array(9);
```

[EDIT]

Actually try this

```
var level1:Array=new Array(
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);


var grid:Array = new Array(11);
public function Level()
{


   for(var row=0;col<11;row++){
     grid[col] = new Array(9);
     for(var col=0;col<9;col++){
        var type = level1[row* 11 + col];
        var obj:Wall = new Wall(col*50,row*50,type);
        grid[col][row] = obj;
        if (type!=0){
           addChild(obj);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: lol, yea dude, you messed up! Geez, talk about no appreciation

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you for your suggestions! I used your source code and fixed a variable you forgot to tweak.